How can I silence TypeScript here without using 'ts-ignore' or writing extraneous JS
As the title says. I don't mind doing some TS gymnastics but I don't want to write additional JS just to please TS.
interface F1 { format: 1; a: number };
interface F2 { format: 2; a: number; b: number };

function f1(a1: F1) {};
function f2(a2: F2) {};

const fs = { 1: f1, 2: f2 };

const q1: F1 = { format: 1, a: 10 };
const q2: F2 = { format: 2, a: 10, b: 20 };

// I have to put `random` here otherwise TypeScript is actually smart enough to figure
// it out. In my real-world application the value comes from the outside and can also not be inferred.
const q: F1|F2 = Math.random() > 0.5
    ? { format: 2, a: 10, b: 30 }
    : { format: 1, a: 30 };

f1(q1);  // 
f2(q2);  // 

fs[q1.format](q1);  // 
fs[q2.format](q2);  // 

fs[q.format](q);  // TypeScript error


"I don't want to write additional JS" Oh well, it's probably not possible then. The standard approach here is ms/TS#47109 but that means you need q to be generic, which needs a function call, as shown in this playground link. Use a type assertion, I guess? That's basically just the same idea as ts-ignore, though, so... oh well.

Can you clarify what exactly you are trying to do?
You can use an any type casting where you do not want Typescript to flag.

@jcalz Well, your playground link helps a lot. I don't mind the little bit of extra JS so much but irl I had 9 props in FMap so I had to do 9 type assertions. Thanks for the help!

@MelvinKosisochukwu I think type casting might defy the point here because I'll lose the strict checking which is a nice to have.

You've run into the issue described at microsoft/TypeScript#30581.
TypeScript cannot follow correlations between multiple mentions of the same value of a union type.  Each utterance of the value is treated as if it were an independent value of the same type. So
fs[q.format](q);  

is analyzed the same as if you had written
declare const q1: typeof q;
declare const q2: typeof q;
fs[q1.format](q2);  

And clearly that wouldn't be safe, because maybe q1 is an F1 but q2 is an F2. So TypeScript warns in both situations, unfortunately.  It would be nice if TypeScript could look at fs[q.format](q) and do a "what if" analysis for imagining q to first be F1 and then imagining it to be F2 and seeing that it works in both cases. But the compiler cannot spend its time analyzing a single line of code once for each possible narrowing of all the values referenced within. In the case here that's just two, but in general it becomes very large (e.g., what do you do when you have x and y and z, each of union types, each with 20 members, and you want to check if x.foo(y.bar(z.baz(x), y), z) should compile?)
I once asked for the ability to just tell TypeScript to do such analysis on an as-requested basis; this is microsoft/TypeScript#25051, and would maybe look like type switch(q) { fs[q.format](q); } which would compile to just { fs[q.format](q); }. But it was declined because even that is too much complexity.

Assuming you want TypeScript to help you keep your code relatively safe, and you don't want to resort to type assertions or the overpowered //@ts-ignore  directive, the officially supported way of doing this is described at microsoft/TypeScript#47109, and involves refactoring away from unions and towards generics.
This requires at least some changes to the emitted JavaScript. You can't write fs[q.format](q) if q is of a union type. It needs to be of the proper sort of generic type. And you can't have a bare unbound generic type, it needs to be in some kind of scope. So you'll need to make a generic function with fs[q.format](q) as its body, and call that function with q as its argument. The question as asked says "I don't want to write additional JS". The answer is then technically "this can't be done, oh well." But the amount of extra JS is pretty minimal here, so maybe it's worthwhile after all. Either way, here's what it looks like.
First we define a "base" interface that serves as a key-value mapping for the underlying types we care about:
interface FMap {
  1: { a: number };
  2: { a: number; b: number }
}

Then we rewrite your F1 and F2 types as a generic F<K> type, where K is from keyof FMap:
type F<K extends keyof FMap = keyof FMap> =
  { [P in K]: { format: P } & FMap[P] }[K]

That's a distributive object type, so F<K1 | K2> is equivalent to F<K1> | F<K2>.  Here F<1> is equivalent to your F1, and F<2> is equivalent to your F<2>.  Note that since K defaults to 1 | 2, then F with no type argument is equivalent to F1 | F2 (which is the type of q).
Now we can write f2, and it is explicitly annotated as having being of a mapped type over FMap's keys. This mapped type is important, because it allows TypeScript to "see" the correlation between fs's properties and FMap for generic K:
const fs: { [K in keyof FMap]: (a: F<K>) => void } = {
  1: (a1) => { },
  2: (a2) => { }
};

Your explicit nongeneric things still work as before:
const q1: F<1> = { format: 1, a: 10 };
const q2: F<2> = { format: 2, a: 10, b: 20 };
const q = Math.random() > 0.5 ? q2 : q1;

fs[q1.format](q1);  // 
fs[q2.format](q2);  // 

But now for arbitrary F, we can write this generic function:
function run<K extends keyof FMap>(q: F<K>) {
  fs[q.format](q); // 
}
run(q); // 

The function body type checks, because q.format is seen to be of type K, and fs[q.format] is therefore seen to be of type (a: F<K>) => void, and since q is of type F<K>, you can call the function with the argument without a problem.
And then run(q) type checks because K is inferred to be 1 | 2.
Playground link to code
